# How to address an element within div tag in selenium

Tags: html, selenium

I have the following html fragment.From which I want to address the element 
 using selenium.  Please advice how I can do this.

```
<div class="mContainer">
<div class="mBox">
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div id="myPlugin" class="plugin" style="height: 691px;">
<div class="mPanel">
<div class="dialpad-box" style="display: none;">
<div class="iconsLeft"> </div>
<div class="iconsRight">
<span class="icons2" onclick="onExit();">
<img src="images/exit-icon.png">
</span>
<span class="icons2" onclick="fullScreenDiv();">
<span id="dialpad" class="icons2">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to address the following element in selenium                                               <span class="icons2" onclick="onExit();">

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? Post the code you have tried and explain why it's not working. Also... add your comment above to the question itself so people don't miss it by not reading the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to select by class with XPath selector

```
xpath=//span[contains(@class, 'ui-autocomplete')]/span[1]
```